# Ownership and Permissions for /var/www

Tags: apache, permissions, server, root

Which is more secure when handling ownership and permissions on /var/www folder?

**Option-1** 
Owner: root:root 
 Folders: 775 
Files: 664

**Option-2**

Owner: root:group1

Folders: 750

Files: 640

Where group1 contains www-data